# how to retrieve a value from a thickbox jquery to the PHP file which called the thickbox?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, thickbox

How to retrieve a value from a thickbox jquery to the PHP file which called the thickbox?..This thickbox is giving hints. So i need to update the database on the basis of whether something happens inside the jquery function. So how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

By the time your jQuery fires your PHP script has already finished, but you can call it again or a seperate php file all together using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

and inside some.php :

```
<?php

$this_is_the_name = $_GET['name'];
$this_is_the_loc = $_GET['location'];

//add these to database or whatever

?>
```

You may wish to put some protection in place to stop SQL injection attacks - anyone could push any data into that script they like.

Comment: but i dont want the thickbox to close. I need the value or the indication that the hint has been used.This indication will be the variable passed on to the PHP through jquery.How do i achieve this passing of a variable from jquery to PHP?

Comment: the ajax function will only call the php file in the background - the browser window will not change.